# How do you interpret the instantaneous causality test?

Tags: regression, interpretation, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I have used the `causality` function to test a VAR(3)-model for Granger causality.

For one variable the following results were computed:

The test found that H0 could not be rejected for the Granger causality test, but for the instant causality test with H0 = No instantaneous causality

But how can I interpret this result now?
What does instantaneous causality mean?

Comment: It seems the following sentence is missing some part at the end: *...but for the instant causality test with H0 = No instantaneous causality ???*. Did you mean *but for the instant causality test with H0 = No instantaneous causality the null hypothesis was rejected*?